# Getting issue in alert dialog box

Tags: flutter, dialog, flutter-dependencies

I am a flutter developer and developing an application for both android and ios. I am getting some issues while completing it.

Please anyone of you can help me on the below issue.

I am developing a flutter application in which we are sending request from one app to another and the app in which we are receiving the request we are facing some issues on the alert dialog box.

The alert dialog box is consists of counter of 45 seconds as if the request is not accepted within the 45 seconds then the alert box expires.

The issue which we are getting that if the dialog box is opened ones and if we close the application and opened again then a new dialog box gets build on the screen with a new counter of 45 seconds. Also as we are getting the notification of the request and if the notification is tapped after the dialog box is opened once then the same thing is happening again.

The dialog box should not get opened again.

Comment: It is hard to help without any code. But it sounds like a state management issue. You need to persist the time when the notification was received in someway and act upon that.